# Using Playwright in a modular Java application

Tags: java, playwright, java-platform-module-system, playwright-java

I would like to use the *Playwright* library in my modular Java application.

This is my main class:

```
package group.test;

import com.microsoft.playwright.Browser;
import com.microsoft.playwright.Page;
import com.microsoft.playwright.Playwright;

public class App 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    try (Playwright playwright = Playwright.create()) 
    {
      Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch();
      Page page = browser.newPage();
      page.navigate("http://playwright.dev");
      System.out.println(page.title());
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the corresponding *module.info* file:

```
module App.module 
{
      requires playwright;
}
```

When I try to build this project using maven's *maven-jlink-plugin* I get the following error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jlink-plugin:3.1.0:jlink (default-jlink) @ test ---
[INFO]  -> module: driver ( C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\playwright\driver\1.17.1\driver-1.17.1.jar )
[INFO]  -> module: playwright ( C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\playwright\playwright\1.17.1\playwright-1.17.1.jar )
[INFO]  -> module: com.google.gson ( C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.6\gson-2.8.6.jar )
[INFO]  -> module: driver.bundle ( C:\Users\User\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\playwright\driver-bundle\1.17.1\driver-bundle-1.17.1.jar )
[INFO]  -> module: App.module ( D:\programming\eclipse-workspace\test\target\classes )
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Error: Module driver.bundle contains package com.microsoft.playwright.impl, module playwright exports package com.microsoft.playwright.impl to driver.bundle
```

I'm new to Java's module system - apparently the problem is that the *driver.bundle* module (which comes with Playwright?) requires a module which exports a package which *driver.bundle* already contains itself. Is this something which can be fixed on my side (as a user) and if so, how?